# Change Image using property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using wpf, below is my image status:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageStatus}"  />
```

Here is the code to change the iamge status, when the image status value is assign:

```
    public readonly DependencyProperty ImageStatusProperty;

    public ImageSource ImageStatus
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageStatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageStatusProperty, value); }
```

I want to have the image changed when the image is assign from the resources.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried binding `Source` property of Image control to your own DP..?? That should work..

Comment: Should I return as image at get; set;

Comment: I have change it to ImageSource, but How can I assign to the Imagestatus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DependencyProperty` must be `static`. [Suggested reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).